# How can I check the syntax of a conf file under sites-available?

Tags: apache

Apache 2.4.29 on Ubuntu 16.04

Hello, All I need to do is to check the synax of a config file for a few virtual hosts I have under the sites-available directory. I am aware reloading apache will check the config but wanted to know is there a command to check the syntax for one config file specifically *without* reloading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`apachectl -t` does that on the enabled configuration, without (re–)starting apache

you can `a2ensite <site>` before and `a2dissite <site>` after to test your configs

Comment: Thanks Jolan, much obliged.